# Point google support map fragment based on Location name given in android

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation

I am using google support fragment map and instead of Latitude and Longitude I want to show the map pointing towards a location that I give when the map becomes ready in the method `OnMapReady(GoogleMap map)`.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

With that information, we cannot really understand your problem. But, if you want to know how the [`OnMapReady(GoogleMap)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/OnMapReadyCallback#onMapReady(com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap)) will work, then this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map) can help you with that.

It explains here the basic step that you need to construct a map.

1. Follow the steps in the [project configuration guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/config) to get the API, obtain a key and add the required attributes to your Android manifest.
2. Add a `Fragment` object to the `Activit`y that will handle the map. The easiest way to do this is to add a `<fragment>` element to the layout file for the Activity.
3. Implement the [`OnMapReadyCallback`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/OnMapReadyCallback) interface and use the `onMapReady(GoogleMap)` callback method to get a handle to the GoogleMap object. The GoogleMap object is the internal representation of the map itself. To set the view options for a map, you modify its GoogleMap object.
4. Call [`getMapAsync()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment.html#getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)) on the fragment to register the callback.

For more information just check the documentation link above.

Now for the Geolocation that you want, this tutorials can guide you on how to do that.

- [Locating user input address in Google Maps Android api v2 with Geocoding api](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/locating-user-input-address-in-google-maps-android-api-v2-with-geocoding-api/)
- [Android Geocoding – Showing User Input Location on Google Map Android API V2](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-geocoding-showing-user-input-location-on-google-map-android-api-v2/)